# Выбор книги по J2EE

Tags: книги, j2ee

Вот что я отрыл:

1. [JavaServer Faces](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5807786/)
2. [Java сервлеты и JSP. Сборник рецептов](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4434287/)
3. [Программирование WEB-приложений на языке Java](http://www.labirint.ru/books/189138/)
4. [Разработка приложений Java EE 6 в NetBeans 7](http://www.labirint.ru/books/378980/)
5. [Java EE 6 и сервер приложений GlassFish 3](http://www.labirint.ru/books/378978/)
6. [Создание web-приложений на языке Java с помощью сервлетов, JSP и EJB](http://www.labirint.ru/books/186954/)

Надо **что-то из этого выбрать**. Я без понятия.

Сразу скажу, что с J2SE я уже знаком, поэтому читать про JEE и знакомиться с основами java по второму разу мне не охота :).

Готов взять **>=1 книг**. Т.е. если 1 книга про 1 технологию, 2ая - про другую, то потихоньку буду изучать обе :)

*p.s. я задавал похожий вопрос, но там - не совсем то.*

Comment: @fori1ton спс, но хотелось бы по подробнее, например почему 2, 4 и 5 в пролёте и т.д.

Comment: Номер 2 плох тем, что концентрируется на конкретных решениях конкретных задач, но не углубляется в подробности именно Servlet API. Номер 4 неплох, в нём рассматриваются в том числе и JSF и такие полезные для enterprise-разработки вещи как SOAP и JPA. В первый раз просмотрел его невнимательно, теперь могу порекомендовать. Номер 5 не столь обширен, да и привязан к одному серверу приложений.

Comment: @fori1ton ок, так (3/6) или 4?

Comment: Сами посудите, в 3/6 - 880 страниц, посвящённых исключительно JSP, а в 4 - 330, посвящённых четырём разным технологиям и одной IDE. Хотите копнуть глубже - берите 3/6. Хотите иметь поверхностное представление обо всём - берите 4.

Comment: @fori1ton тогда беру обе :). p.s. если хотите, оформите ответом - приму и плюсану

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если выбор **именно из этих** книг, то сначала 3 или 6 (очень странно, у них один автор, одинаковое число страниц, выпущены одним издательством в одном и том же 2009 году; чёрт, да у них даже содержания совпадают!). Пункт 1 оставьте на потом, когда прочтёте 3 или 6. На мой взгляд важно сначала понять, как работают сервлеты на низком уровне, а затем браться за фреймворки. Номер 2 плох тем, что концентрируется на конкретных решениях конкретных задач, но не углубляется в подробности именно Servlet API. Номер 4 неплох, в нём рассматриваются в том числе и JSF и такие полезные для enterprise-разработки вещи как SOAP и JPA. Номер 5 не столь обширен, да и привязан к одному серверу приложений. В общем, сами посудите, в 3/6 - 880 страниц, посвящённых исключительно JSP, а в 4 - 330, посвящённых четырём разным технологиям и одной IDE. Хотите копнуть глубже - берите 3/6. Хотите иметь поверхностное представление обо всём - берите 4.